# Openshift 3 installation failed

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

I am getting several issues when trying to install Openshift 3 with ansible. All the errors are differents at each installation but they always rely on a pair of node

**Version**

`openshift-ansible from git repo: openshift-ansible-3.6.173.0.32-1`

`ansible: 2.3.0.0`

**Steps To Reproduce**

- Take two nodes and one master

  - node1.my-site.com
  - node2.my-site.com
  - master.my-site.com
- Follow prerequesites on the openshift documentation.
- Follow host preparation on the openshift documentation.
- Write approximatively the same hosts as [single master and multiple nodes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#single-master)
- `ansible-playbook playbooks/byo/config.yml`

Here is my real playbook:

```
# to be save in /etc/ansible/hosts.
# coming from https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#single-master

# Create an OSEv3 group that contains the masters and nodes groups
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
# SSH user, this user should allow ssh based auth without requiring a password
ansible_ssh_user=root

# If ansible_ssh_user is not root, ansible_become must be set to true
#ansible_become=true

openshift_deployment_type=origin

openshift_disable_check=memory_availability

# uncomment the following to enable htpasswd authentication; defaults to DenyAllPasswordIdentityProvider
#openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]

# host group for masters
[masters]
master.my-site.com

# host group for etcd
[etcd]
master.my-site.com

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
node1.my-site.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'default'}"
node2.my-site.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'default'}"
infra-node1.my-site.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
infra-node2.my-site.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
```

This is basically a copy paste of the one in the docs except that I changed the zones for my nodes.

**An important note**: Maybe I am doing the thing wrongly:
node1.my-site.com resolves the same ip as infra-node1.my-site.com
node2.my-site.com resolves the same ip as infra-node2.my-site.com

I don't know if it is the correct way but in the documentation they just talk about 2 nodes so I suspected that it was supposed to resolve same IP.

***Observed Results***

After approximatively 10 or 20 minutes deployment fail with random errors:

```
Failure summary:

  1. Host:     node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "docker_storage":
               Some dependencies are required in order to query docker storage on host:
               Unable to install required packages on this host:
                   python-docker-py
               Failure talking to yum: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/gen/primary_db.sqlite'

               check "package_availability":
               Error with yum repository configuration: updates: Check uncompressed DB failed

  2. Host:     infra-node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "docker_storage":
               Some dependencies are required in order to query docker storage on host:
               Unable to install required packages on this host:
                   python-docker-py
               Failure talking to yum: updates: Check uncompressed DB failed
```

This one was strange `'/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/gen/primary_db.sqlite'` was there verification

```
Failure summary:

  1. Host:     infra-node1.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_version":
               MODULE FAILURE

               check "package_availability":
               Error with yum repository configuration: File /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/metalink.xml is not XML

  2. Host:     node1.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_version":
               MODULE FAILURE

  3. Host:     infra-node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_version":
               MODULE FAILURE

               check "package_availability":
               Error with yum repository configuration: File /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/metalink.xml does not exist

  4. Host:     node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_version":
               MODULE FAILURE

               check "package_availability":
               Error with yum repository configuration: File /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/metalink.xml does not exist
```

This one file was not an XML I confirm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metalink version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.metalinker.org/" type="dynamic" pubdate="Tue, 12 Sep 2017 20:22:13 GMT" generator="mirrormanager" xmlns:mm0="http://fedorahosted.org/mirrormanager">
  <files>
    <file name="repomd.xml">
      <resources maxconnections="1">
        <url protocol="blablabla">http://blablabla</url>
        ...
        ...
        <url protocol="blablabla">http://blablabla</url>
      </resources>
    </file>
  </files>
</metalink>
x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml</url>                         <==== What?????
        <url protocol="blablabla">http://blablabla</url>
      </resources>
    </file>
  </files>
</metalink>
```

Third error I do not understand it at all as it is a old.tmp (the repomd.xml was there)

```
Failure summary:

  1. Host:     infra-node1.my-site.com
     Play:     Disable excluders
     Task:     openshift_excluder : Install docker excluder
     Message:  Failure talking to yum: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos-openshift-origin/repomd.xml.old.tmp'
```

Anothere one:

```
Failure summary:

  1. Host:     node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_availability":
               Error with yum repository configuration: updates: Check uncompressed DB failed

  2. Host:     infra-node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_availability":
               Error with yum repository configuration: updates: Check uncompressed DB failed
```

And the last one:

```
Failure summary:

  1. Host:     node1.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_availability":
               Unexpected error with yum repository: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/gen/primary_db.sqlite'

  2. Host:     node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_version":
               MODULE FAILURE

               check "package_availability":
               Unexpected error with yum repository: /builddir/build/BUILD/Python-2.7.5/Objects/stringobject.c:3902: bad argument to internal function

  3. Host:     infra-node2.my-site.com
     Play:     Verify Requirements
     Task:     openshift_health_check
     Message:  One or more checks failed
     Details:  check "package_availability":
               Unexpected error with yum install/update: database disk image is malformed
```

**Additional Information**

Provide any additional information which may help us diagnose the
issue.

- OS: `centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64`
- I think I do not do something correct with the hosts file because the concern are almost always the pair node1 infra-node1, node2 infra-node2
- Master is 15GB of ram and 2 vcpu, nodes are 8 GB and 2 vcpu
- I am hosted to OVH
- I killed my platform for security reason

Answer (score -1):

try this link very good explanation.
https://keithtenzer.com/2017/08/11/openshift-3-6-fast-track-everything-you-need-nothing-you-dont/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.